# ng-repeat is not working for the json value

Tags: angularjs

I have a code like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tagJson in tagList">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tagJson">
        <td width="48%" ng-class-odd="'evn'" ng-class-even="'odd'">
            {{key}}
        </td>
        <td width="48%" ng-class-odd="'evn'" ng-class-even="'odd'">
            {{value}}
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

where `tagList` is :

```
[{a:1},{a:1}]
```

But the `key` and `value` are empty! Not sure why thats the case. If i try to print `tagJson` in the html like:

```
{{tagJson}}
```

it does print:

```
{a:1}
{a:1}
```

but `key` and `value` doesnt work!

Where I'm making the mistakes?

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/126/

Comment: please create a sample online (jsfiddle or plnkr)

Comment: tagJson is an object not an array

Comment: you do not see anything because this is invalid markup for the table. you have `div` elements inside.

Comment: @akonsu you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual reason why you don't see anything is, as akonsu posted, because you're producing invalid html.

To keep the values in seperate table cells, you can use `ng-repeat-start/end`, e.g.:

```js
var MainCtrl = function () {
  this.tagList = [{a:1}, {b:2}];
};

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('Main', MainCtrl)
;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="Main as main">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="tagJson in main.tagList">
      <td ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in tagJson" width="48%" ng-class-odd="'evn'" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        {{key}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat-end width="48%" ng-class-odd="'evn'" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        {{value}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not see anything because this is invalid markup for the table. You have `div` elements inside.

maybe this?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="tagJson in tagList">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in tagJson">
        {{key}}={{value}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

but to emit the markup that you wanted, I think you need a custom directive for that.

Comment: without `div` how can I iterate over json and put data to `tr`. Can you give me the jsfiddle link?

Comment: deleted my answer @akonsu answer is right, refer this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9ooSs5NWC9ygfl9N4Hzg?p=preview , upvote him